# Adding one extra column in CMS_User table and after deleting these column. I am not able to logon on cmsdesk

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I add one extra column in CMS_User table and after deleting these column. I am not  able to logon on cmsdesk

And Getting the following error "The value for field 'Test' is missing. You need to initialize the field before executing this operation."

Comment: Did you add/delete the column from CMS UI, using API, by SQL query or by combination of one of these?

Answer (score 0):

If you added the column in the CMS rather than manually in an SQL viewer, then there's probably still a reference to it in one of Kentico's SQL definition tables.

Have a look at `CMS_Class.ClassXmlSchema` (in a SQL viewer like MSSQL Management Studio) - an XML of the columns and other relevant data for other tables (including `CMS_User`) for reference to your old column.